# How to add a custom field to a release from the workspace level?

Tags: rally

I am trying to add a custom field for releases, since our team needs to be able to specify the release time (right now end date always defaults to 11:59 so that's not working for us). The problem is that we don't see "release" under the work items that custom fields can be added to. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked our subscription on rally1.rallydev.com and release was in the list of types on the Workspace Fields page.  If you're not seeing it in your subscription you may want to follow up with your subscription admin and/or Rally support.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, it was about my subscription permission. One thing though, the issue is that when we choose "date" as the type of the field, you can set up whichever date without a problem, but the time is always set to 11:59:00, and there's no way to change it.

Comment: That probably falls under the category of feature request- you're right though- currently we have custom date fields but there is no concept of a custom date+time field...